# How to do calculations in R with multiple data.frames or arrays?

Tags: arrays, r, lapply, do.call

UPDATED - I need to perform calculations using 100+ 2-dimensional tables. I understand the tables can be imported into R as data.frames or arrays.

Here is an example that illustrates my problem. For simplification, my many tables are represented by d1, d2, dd2 and dd3. Note that I added more data.frames into the list because the solution that @BondedDust proposed, that was replacing 'sum' by '+' worked when the list had 2 data.frames in it, but not the 4 data.frames.

```
d1 = mtcars
d2 = d1*2
dd2 = d2 * 2
dd3 = d2 * d2
```

Below, d3 would be my desired final output if the operation were the '+'. But I need a way to automate this process.

```
d3 = d1+d2 + dd2 + dd3 
> str(d3)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  2793 2793 3279 2898 2229 ...
 $ cyl : num  258 258 124 258 440 258 440 124 124 258 ...
 $ disp: num  154720 154720 70740 401190 780120 ...
 $ hp  : num  73370 73370 52545 73370 184975 ...
 $ drat: num  118.6 118.6 115.9 78.5 81.6 ...
 $ wt  : num  59.5 69.7 48.5 84.5 95.1 ...
 $ qsec: num  1741 1857 2208 2404 1857 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 13 13 0 13 0 13 13 13 ...
 $ am  : num  13 13 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  124 124 124 75 75 75 75 124 124 124 ...
 $ carb: num  124 124 13 13 38 13 124 38 38 124 ...
```

So I tried with lists, but when I use do.call with '+' with the 4 data.frames in the list it doesn't work.

```
l1 = list(d1,d2,dd2,dd3)
str(l1)

> str(l1)
List of 4
 $ :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...

d4 = do.call('+', l1)
Error in `+`(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4,  : 
  unused arguments (list(mpg = c(84, 84, 91.2, 85.6, 74.8, 72.4, 57.2, 97.6, 91.2, 76.8, 71.2, 65.6, 69.2, 60.8, 41.6, 41.6, 58.8, 129.6, 121.6, 135.6, 86, 62, 60.8, 53.2, 76.8, 109.2, 104, 121.6, 63.2, 78.8, 60, 85.6), cyl = c(24
```

This post [R - Vector/ Array Addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900690/r-vector-array-addition) shows a similar problem, but they used arrays instead of data.frames. So, I tried converting the data.frames to arrays using this:

```
d5 = lapply(l1, function(x) data.matrix(x))
```

But d5 doesn't have the correct structure to do for example:

```
d6 = apply(d5,1:2,sum)
```

So, I'm not sure if the problem is in the way I'm using the lapply, the do.call or what. Any help or direction will be appreciated. Sorry if I missed a previous post that already addressed this issue, I've been searching the web all day and tried many different options and couldn't get a desirable outcome.
Thanks!

Comment: are your 100  dataframe , the same dimensions. You can 1) join the dataframes together to make a really huge df, if resources permits,  and do sum. 2) Use a for loop

Comment: @LuluPor: `sum` would be the wrong function to try. It's not vectorized. Need to use "+"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. @BondedDust your solution worked with the list of two data.frames, as soon as I added the others I got an error message. I'll update the example so I show the error I get.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that these are not "tables", at least in technical R parlance. R tables are actually matrices or arrays and it's very easy to use "+", "-", "/" or "*" with then to do element-wise operations. You are showing R dataframes. They are lists and could be added name by name. You can loop over the names in the first dataframe and then add with "+" along columns:

```
 d3 <- as.data.frame(
              lapply(names(d1), function(x){ d1[ , x, drop=FALSE] + d2[ ,x]} ) )
 str(d3)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  63 63 68.4 64.2 56.1 54.3 42.9 73.2 68.4 57.6 ...
 $ cyl : num  18 18 12 18 24 18 24 12 12 18 ...
 $ disp: num  480 480 324 774 1080 ...
 $ hp  : num  330 330 279 330 525 315 735 186 285 369 ...
 $ drat: num  11.7 11.7 11.55 9.24 9.45 ...
 $ wt  : num  7.86 8.62 6.96 9.64 10.32 ...
 $ qsec: num  49.4 51.1 55.8 58.3 51.1 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 3 3 0 3 0 3 3 3 ...
 $ am  : num  3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  12 12 12 9 9 9 9 12 12 12 ...
 $ carb: num  12 12 3 3 6 3 12 6 6 12 ...
```

The as.data.frame is needed because lapply will return a list (which is what a dataframe really is) but it will remove the attributes that establish a list as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution based on @biobirdman's comment. All the data.frames have the same structure.

In the context of the real model this works if you have access to a big computer, which I may eventually, so I'll use this one.

```
d5=do.call('rbind',l1)
d5.rnames =rep(rownames(l1[[1]]),times=length(l1)) #not sure this is the best way to add a col with the names to do the aggregation
d5$reg=d5.rnames
d6 = aggregate(d5[,1:11], by=list(d5$reg), FUN=sum)
```